# Tomcat Servlet: 404 status when src/main/webapp/WEB-INF and no error when root/WEB-INF

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have a **LoginServlet.java**:

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
      response.getWriter().println("HELLO THERE");
}
```

and this code in **web.xml** (among other things):

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/LoginResult.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.web.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
```

I try to go to URL: `http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/LoginResult.do` and get a `HTTP Status 404 – Not Found` error.

Why? It seems like Tomcat can't find the serlvet, otherwise it would be able to output the text since its fairly easy.

My project structure:

```
ProjectName
-----------index.jsp
-----------pom.xml
-----------src
--------------main
------------------java
----------------------com
-------------------------web
---------------------------------LoginServlet.java
------------------webapp
------------------------WEB-INF
-------------------------------classes
--------------------------------------com
------------------------------------------web
---------------------------------------------LoginServlet.class
```

**EDIT**: I figured out a solution of sorts: if I place `WEB-INF` folder with all its contents into root `ProjectName` it works fine and I can access the servlet. However, I've seen this (like in my question) project structure recommended in tutorials. How do I make it work with a project structure when `WEB-INF` is located inside `src/main/webapp`? I use Maven a bit (download dependencies and specify target output directory). Do I need to make some changes in `pom.xml` to make it work?

**EDIT2**: Here's my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.util</groupId>
    <artifactId>testproject</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Test Project</name>
    <url>https://test.com</url>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-util -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0-RC1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Using logback-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-enforcer-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <start-class>com.web.LoginServlet</start-class>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\classes</outputDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>

                            <artifactItems>

                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>8.0.30.2</version>
                                    <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>

                            </artifactItems>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>

            </plugin>


            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I run `mvn package` it creates a `testproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war` and `testproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war.original` in `root/target`. But then when I go to `http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/LoginResult.do` it's still `404` error.

I tried putting `testproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war` and `testproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war.original` in `root` - didn't work, still `404` error, then I tried putting it into `Tomcat 8.5/webapps` - still `404`.

Comment: What des your WAR file look like?

Comment: @user207421 I don't use one? I (maven) just place `.class` files into `WEB-INF/classes` and tomcat seems to take it from there.

Comment: Before I used maven I had `WEB-INF` inside the root and I compiled and moved `.class`es from `root/target/classes` manually (and it worked).

Comment: @user207421 I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing has nothing to do with the wrongly placed resources. I just created a Maven project with the same structure as yours and everything works fine. The only thing you're doing wrong is that you use the URI:

```
http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/LoginResult.do
```

As you wrote above the generated **war** file is named **testproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war**. So if you drop this file in the **webapps** folder of Tomcat, your correct URL should be:

```
http://localhost:8080/testproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT/LoginResult.do
```

If you want to use your URL, you should adjust your POM as follows:

```
.............
<build>
    <finalName>ProjectName</finalName>
    ..................
</build>
```

This will produce **Projectname.war** when you build with Maven, and after deploying you can use:

```
http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/LoginResult.do
```

Lastly, you don't need the following line in your POM and should remove it (I am not sure whether you want to put the generated artifacts under your source tree!):

```
<outputDirectory>${basedir}\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\classes</outputDirectory>
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work now. One of my mistakes was placing `index.jsp` inside project's root instead of `src/main/webapp`. `<finalName>` doesn't work however. Do I need to change my `pom.xml` somewhere else to include `finalName` property?

Comment: I also get two extra folders inside `tomcat/webapps`: `TestProjectartifact` and `TestProjectartifact_war`. Is this normal? It kind of takes up space inside `tomcat/webapps` - and the mechanism is the same - tomcat takes any folder inside `webapps` and deploys its `WEB-INF` contents. So in the end even this 'correct' approach is based on simply placing `WEB-INF` inside `tomcat/webapps/SomeName`, am I right?

Comment: @parsecer `<finalName>` should be placed directly under the `<build>` element as shown above in the answer. **TestProjectartifact** and **TestProjectartifact_war** can only be under Tomcat's `webapps` folder only if you copy them manually or you configure your system to do so automatically. No other possibility is known to me. If you're sure that the artifacts are of the test project you can safely delete them.