# Maven: copy paste WEB-INF into root after packaging copy folder

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jakarta-ee, ant

I have a project like this:

```
TestArt
-----------index.jsp
-----------pom.xml
-----------src
--------------main
------------------java/com/web/LoginServlet.java
------------------webapp/WEB-INF/classes/com/web/LoginServlet.class
-----------target
-----------------testproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
-----------------testproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war.original
-----------------testproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT
----------------------------------META-INF
----------------------------------WEB-INF
---------------------------------------classes/com/web/LoginServlet.class
---------------------------------------lib (here are all the jars)
```

and **pom.xml** like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.util</groupId>
    <artifactId>testproject</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Test Project</name>
    <url>https://test.com</url>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <start-class>com.web.LoginServlet</start-class>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\classes</outputDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>

                            <artifactItems>

                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>8.0.30.2</version>
                                    <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>

                            </artifactItems>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>

            </plugin>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    </build>
</project>
```

After I run **mvn package** it creates **META-INF** and **WEB-INF** folders inside **root/target** folder and also places **.war** files in there.

I want maven to also copy a **WEB-INF** folder from **target** into the root (**TestArt**) once the packaging is done. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Trust me: you do not want that. Builds should only create/alter files in `target`, nowhere else. What is your aim?

Comment: I've run into a problem I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54718941/tomcat-servlet-404-status-when-src-main-webapp-web-inf-and-no-error-when-root-w) (tl;dr - unless `WEB-INF` is inside root folder, I can't access servlets), so I'm trying to make a temporary solution (namely placing `WEB-INF` into root which works right now) work, until I find a permanent correct one.

Comment: Follow the convention over configuration...first put your resources into `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` and your usual source code into `src/main/java` etc. and remove the `<outputDirectory>..</outputDirectory>` configuration cause it's wrong in this scenario furthermore remove maven-dependency-plugin and the copy goal etc. let spring-boot-maven-plugin do it's work...

Comment: Another thing remove the class files from `webapp/WEB-INF/classes/com/web/LoginServlet.class` which is caused by your strange configuration via `<outputDirectory>..</outputDirectory>`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't figure it out with `Ant`, so I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17852174/4759176). In my case it would look like this:

```
  <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-resources</id>
                <!-- here the phase you need -->
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/WEB-INF</outputDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>target/testproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
  </plugin>
```

**EDIT**: This plugin copy pastes files one by one, instead of taking a folder and copy pasting it with all it files once. This leads to broken links between classes and directories and nothing seems to work. For now, I'm using the `batch` script:

```
xcopy "C:\...\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\TestArt\target\testproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF" "C:\...\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\TestArt\WEB-INF\" /E /Y
```

Using [this answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21871221/4759176) Maven plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>sign</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <exec executable="${basedir}\copy.bat">

                            </exec>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I managed to achieve a desired result.

But if there are solutions in pure Maven that would copy a directory all at once, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: Turns out there's something wrong with this approach - although copying of files works fine, I get a `404` error when using this approach. However if I copypaste `WEB-INF` manually (or copypaste all files in root's `WEB-INF` with target's `WEB-INF`) , everything works fine.

Comment: If I take `lib` folder from target's `WEB-INF` and replace root's `WEB-INF` with that folder, I can get to the `index.jsp` page, but my servlets break with error: `java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 4022320623 in class file`.

Comment: It looks like some connections between the `.class` files and libraries break this way - because this plugin copies files one by one and not the whole directories at once.

Comment: Do not do this cause it's the wrong path..see my comments.

Answer (score 2):

I really would recommend to spend time on fixing the original problem, but if you want:

Use Maven Antrun Plugin to copy a folder from one place to another, as described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/694175/927493

The details of the copy command in Ant are explained here:

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html